# adding HTML select of countries to multiple places

Tags: html

So I wanna have a HTML select of countries on multiple places on my website (couple of forms)
I have this big select with all the countries.  But what now?
What is the most elegant way to "include" it in multiple html files and not bloating them/duplicate code

Comment: Didn't got your question

Comment: Use AJAX to load your options to all places where it is needed. That way you have a central point to maintain your list in case of changes.

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to be a special case of “How do I include an HTML file in an HTML file?”, and the practical answer is “You don’t”. You can do inclusion server-side, in many technologies (e.g., PHP), but that’s a different issue. You can do inclusion with client-side JavaScript, but that makes the control nonexistent when JavaScript is disabled (or a runtime error occurs in it).

In the case of country selection menu, the best approach is not to have one, except if it is very small and specialized (I think a list of EU member states is at the upper limit, if not above). Large dropdowns have poor usability. Besides, a list of countries is difficult to maintain – I think I have *never* seen (on web pages) a dropdown that has a *correct* list of the countries of the world.

Instead, use a text input box. If you need to parse the input to a country code (and verify that it is a recognized country), do that server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to either create or use some existing js widget which can be used in multiple html files. Check this example for your reference. [Country Select Example](http://dound.com/2010/05/country-and-state-chooser-javascript-widget/)

In this case you only need to write code for only once.

Comment: And what happens when JavaScript is disabled in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can add in some javascript with your countries in and (using jQuery) can do something along the lines of

```
var countries = ["UK", "USA", "India"]; //list all countries in one place

$.each(countries, function(i, val){
   $("#CountryList").append(<option value="'+val+'">'+val+'</option>');
});
```

This assumes that CountryList is an empty select element on each page. This code is only for guidance and you will need to write your own implementation to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use php, you can create the HTML select list once inside a file, and then just include the file everywhere you need it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Or you can make a class and return the list as the output of a method or static method of that class, wherever you need it, on any php page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php